# Microsoft Edge User Agent from modern.ie

Tags: microsoft-edge

I downloaded a vm from modern.ie for Win10, MS Edge (IE 11)

When I look at the userAgent (JS code in the console : navigator.userAgent), I get:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0); Win64; x64)"

From what I can see on this post from MS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx), the user agent should have "Edge" token:

"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12."

I'm wondering what is causing this? Any ideas?

My version of IE11 is : 
Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0

Here's a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the IE11 user agent string in Windows 10 or the Edge user agent string in Windows 10?

Comment: About Edge. We've experienced the same...

Comment: Let's hope it's only a mistake: https://twitter.com/anowodzinski/status/633609005538115584

Comment: The Mac Parallels build has a correct UA string. I wonder what kind of mistake could lead to a bug like that manifesting only in a couple of VMs...

Comment: What VM did you download? All the VMs are created from the same ISO file and the same process so that is definitely not expected.

Comment: I downloaded the VM for Microsoft Edge on Win10 from here: http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/

Comment: To be more precise: Virtual Machine: Microsoft Edge for Win10, Select Platform: Virtual Box. I did this yesterday, and the user agent was the one mentioned in the post. Then, I downloaded the .iso on this site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: I've downloaded the Windows - Virtual Box one and it has the right userAgent. I'll check with a mac now.

Comment: Cool. Let me know. I added a screenshot to the post.

Comment: I can repro this on a Mac with the VM for Mac. I'm going to try importing the VM for PC (only difference should be the integration tools) to see if that still repros and know if it is an issue with Virtual Box (Win10 is not official supported by them yet).

Comment: That's great. Thanks @AntónMolleda!

Comment: Yep, same here; VBox VM Edge's `navigator.userAgent` only includes the first chunk of the official user agent string.

Answer (score 11):

Can confirm this is an issue with the Mac VM for VirtualBox. If you download the PC version instead and use if from your Mac it will have the right userAgent (you will also have to install the integration tools).
We are investigating where the problem is coming from and will update the VMs once it is fixed.

**Edit:**
Since last Friday this should be fixed. Please download again the file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I will try the one for PC on my mac. Would be curious to know what was the issue once it's found.

Comment: This drove me mad trying to find out why CKEditor wasn't working. This was why!

Answer (score 0):

It must be some issue with the VM itself, have you tried the HyperV_2012 version? You can also try the RemoteIE tool : https://remote.modern.ie/subscribe

Comment: Thanks Rami. I haven't tried the HyperV_2012 version. I'll give it a shot at the PC version and if that doesn't work, I'll try this one.